# Cálculo de soma de dígitos

Tags: python

> Escreva um programa que receba um número inteiro na entrada, calcule e imprima a soma dos dígitos deste número na saída
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> >>>Digite um número inteiro: 123
>
> >>>6
> ```
>
> Dica: Para separar os dígitos, lembre-se: o operador "//" faz uma divisão inteira jogando fora o resto, ou seja, aquilo que é menor que o divisor; O operador "%" devolve apenas o resto da divisão inteira jogando fora o resultado, ou seja, tudo que é maior ou igual ao divisor.

Eu fiz o código, porém, ele está com um bug de repetição que não consigo resolver. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
x=int(input("Digite um número para que seus digitos sejam somados: "))

soma=0
while (x>0):
    resto = (x // 10)%10
    resto_cont=(x%10)
    resto_cont2=(x//100)
    soma = resto + resto_cont + resto_cont2
print("valor é", soma)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu programa fica preso dentro do `while` e nunca sai porque o valor de `x` nunca muda.

Além disso, se você tem um `while` percorrendo os dígitos, você deveria ter `soma = soma + alguma_outra_coisa`.

Também é de se notar que no `while`, você deveria estar separando o último dígito dos demais. Você de fato está separando o último, mas na hora de separar os demais, está fazendo errado e esquecendo-se que você está dentro do `while`.

Faça assim:

```
x = int(input("Digite um número para que seus dígitos sejam somados: "))

soma = 0
while x > 0:
    resto = x % 10
    x = x // 10
    soma = soma + resto

print("O valor é", soma)
```

Com essa entrada:

```
123
```

Essa é a saída:

```
O valor é 6
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/4ZQKiX)

Comment: Ah, muito obrigada pela ajuda!!!!